# Angular Multi Provider dependency order

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

Does the Angular DI Multi Provider mechanism **guarantee** some sort of order?

Example:

```
const TOKEN: OpaqueToken = new OpaqueToken('token');

@Injectable() 
class MyService (@Inject(TOKEN) deps: any[]) {/* What is order of deps? */}

@NgModule ({
  providers: [ 
    {provide: TOKEN, multi: true, useValue: 1},
    {provide: TOKEN, multi: true, useValue: 2},
    {provide: TOKEN, multi: true, useValue: 3},
    MyService
})
class MyModule {}
```

Comment: It should be the order they are added but I don't know about guarantees. You can provide an array instead of `multi: true` to get the values in the defined order.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer In this simple example you could inject array of those values but in more complex case if I want to inject some classes that depends on other things it will not work

Comment: I see. Sorry, no better idea.

Comment: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular2/2015/11/23/multi-providers-in-angular-2.html may help... looks like only the last one is present ...!  Also, as mentioned in this blog, multi providers also can’t be mixed with normal providers. This makes sense since we either extend or override a provider for a token.

Comment: I have the same question, created an issue here, because I could not find documentation: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23059

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes. Although I cannot find the documentation to say definitively. However, from personal experience, I can say that they're always provided in the same order. We use multiple HttpInterceptors as well as some injectable actions throughout our applications and they're always injected in the order they're provided. Also, since [APP_INITIALIZER](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER) and [HTTP_INTERCEPTOR](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HTTP_INTERCEPTORS) are provided this way I would assume that it's true even more so. You wouldn't want your HTTP_INTERCEPTOR's being provided in random order.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to inject class A in component X, for example, that depends on other classes, the best way to go about it is to inject those classes in class A. In component X, you still need to declare all of the services. For example:
component X:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import {
  CarService, CarService2, CarService3,
  EngineService, EngineService2, TiresService
} from './car.services';
```

car.services.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

/// Model ///
export class Car {
}

export class Engine {
}

export class Tires {
}

//// Engine services ///
@Injectable()
export class EngineService {
}

@Injectable()
export class EngineService2 {
}

//// Tire services ///
@Injectable()
export class TiresService {
}

/// Car Services ///
@Injectable()
export class CarService {
  id = 'C1';
  constructor(
    protected engineService: EngineService,
    protected tiresService: TiresService) { }
}

@Injectable()
export class CarService2 extends CarService {
  id = 'C2';
  constructor(
    protected engineService: EngineService,
    protected tiresService: TiresService) {
    super(engineService, tiresService);
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class CarService3 extends CarService2 {
  id = 'C3';
  constructor(
    protected engineService: EngineService,
    protected tiresService: TiresService) {
    super(engineService, tiresService);
  }

}
```

https://stackblitz.com/angular/vomexgeqgdj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcar.services.ts